# BigDecimal method call causes compile time error

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I am trying to format and save a double using BigDecimal, as I want to use the rounding modes available to it. This code however causes a compilation error:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Format {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        double result = 123.456;
        int decimalPlaces = 2;

        result = BigDecimal.valueOf(result).setScale(decimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

The error encountered:

```
Format.java:10: error: incompatible types: BigDecimal cannot be converted to double
        result = BigDecimal.valueOf(result).setScale(decimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

The value of result I am looking for is:

```
123.46
```

Please help me understand how to correct this.

Edit: I understand that my brevity in asking the question has lead to the question being down voted. It appears as if I encountered a compile error and immediately came to ask for a solution which is not the case. I'll take the time to give clearer exposition next time.

Comment: how is this: "incompatible types: BigDecimal cannot be converted to double" not clear?

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for: BigDecimal.valueOf(result).setScale(decimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because your variable `result` is of type `double`, while operations on a BigDecimal will usually produce values of type BigDecimal. You cannot put a BigDecimal in a variable of type `double`. You need a variable of type BigDecimal.

Which is what the error message was very clearly telling you, and it is rather concerning that you chose to ignore it and come ask here instead.

> The value of result I am looking for is:
>
> `123.46`

A `double` is a rather wrong tool for getting to that. doubles are approximate, and you're telling that you want a very exact result and nothing else than that result. Therefore, not an approximation.

If your only goal is to display `123.46` as a result of the number 123.456 you had and that you round to two decimals, then the key word is **display**. The right tool for displaying text is a String, not a double.

Use a DecimalFormat.

```
NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String s = format.format(result);

System.out.println(s);
```

No need for BigDecimal.

Comment: I was about to say "But what about rounding mode?" -  and then I noticed that the `DecimalFormat` class has [setRoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)) since Java 1.6 - for all your formatting needs.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov that, and the wanted rounding mode is half-up. That is to say the universal default, and what most stuff do when they don't have a rounding mode setting and their advertised purpose is not to truncate.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thank you for your comment. I did not consider this the correct answer for that exact reason. Now I know better due to your comment.

Comment: It is correct that I don't need BigDecimal. I simply didn't know of another way to use Rounding without having to roll my own. I will be clearer in asking my question next time.

Comment: @DevStep I don't think you made a mistake of not asking clearly enough. It sounded like you were not aware of your options and that is why I offered one that seemed the more straightforward given the problem you seemed to have.

Answer (score 1):

It might be too obvious, but you cannot assign a `double` to a `BigDecimal`.

```
BigDecimal decimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(result)
    .setScale(decimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(decimal);
```

Which gives the correct output of 123.46.

If you want a `double` instead, use `BigDecimal.doubleValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`BigDecimal::setScale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,java.math.RoundingMode)) return `BigDecimal` not a `double`, You have to use [`BigDecimal::doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()) to get the double value, like this :

```
result = BigDecimal.valueOf(result)
        .setScale(decimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        .doubleValue();

System.out.println(result);// 123.46
```

Answer (score 0):

setScale() returns a BigDecimal which you are casting to double and hence the error.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int)